# Bug: Export sometimes adds unwanted background to PDF files

Tags: graphics, export, bugs, pdf-format

**Update:** WRI confirmed that this is a known issue with `Export` on 2015-05-14.

I am trying to export the outputs of some Plot expressions as PDF files for inclusion in a $\LaTeX$ document.

The two graphs are produced using the following code:

```
Plot[{
  PDF[NormalDistribution[], x],
  PDF[NormalDistribution[-4, 1], x],
  PDF[NormalDistribution[2, 1], x]
  },
 {x, -8, 6},
 AxesLabel -> {None, None},
 Ticks -> {Automatic, None},
 Axes -> {True, False}
 ]
Export["NormalDistMean.pdf", %]
Plot[{
  PDF[NormalDistribution[], x],
  PDF[NormalDistribution[-4, 1], x],
  PDF[NormalDistribution[2, 1], x]
  },
 {x, -8, 6},
 AxesLabel -> {None, None},
 Ticks -> {Automatic, None},
 Axes -> {True, False},
 PlotLegends -> {"N(0,1)", "N(-4,1)", "N(2,1)"}
 ]
Export["NormalDistMeanAns.pdf", %]
```

---

Then I included them in a $\LaTeX$ document (Beamer). The complete documents are shown below for the first PDF (no legends) and second PDF (with legends), respectively:

[image: no legends]

[image: with legends]

The first graph shows up in the $\LaTeX$ document with a white background, whereas the second one doesn't, i.e. the plot was transparent, as was the original intended outcome for both.

Here is the question: **How do I make the first PDF like the second one?**

Thanks!

---

The $\LaTeX$ (beamer) code is included below for those who are interested.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\mode<presentation>{
    \usetheme{Darmstadt} %Best
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % navigation bars

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Mean}
  \centering
  \only<1>{
   \begin{block}{Can you find the $\mu$ for each of the $N(\mu,1^2)$ density curves?}
    \includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight]{NormalDistMean.pdf}
   \end{block}
  }
  \only<2>{
   \begin{block}{Can you find the $\mu$ for each of the $N(\mu,1^2)$ density curves?}
    \includegraphics[height=0.6\textheight]{NormalDistMeanAns.pdf}
   \end{block}
  }
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `Background -> None` as an option to your plots? This seems to work on MMA v.10.1.0 on Win7-64bit

Comment: @MarcoB I am using the same MMA V10.1.0 on Win7 X64. But it did not seem to work. How did you know whether it worked? Did you compile it in latex as well? As far as I can tell, PDF reader won't tell the difference since both background are white?

Comment: I didn't compile it into latex, but I imported the PDF files into a vector graphics program ([InkScape](https://inkscape.org/en/): you should check it out, it's free / open source, and it's great). I then ungrouped the imported PDF vector graphics. The first PDF without the Background->None option had a white background panel; when I used Background->None, the white background was not there anymore, so effectively the plot was transparent.

Comment: @MarcoB Hmmmm, that's odd! Yes, I know about InkScape. Thanks! I have Acrobat, so I can verify this myself too. It does not work on my system. I have also tried to latex it. The problem still remains.

Comment: Have you tried exporting to EPS rather than PDF, to see if it makes any difference? I'm not familiar with latex, so I don't know if that would work just as well to produce your final document.

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, any post-script (.PS, .PDF, .EPS) will work fine with latex. I personally tend to use PDF since it is more common for people to open with any (free) PDF reader. Just for the sake of my current, I can use EPS, it works.

Comment: I delved a bit deeper in the issue, and I can't explain this behavior of `Export`. It looks like a bug to me. I've posted an answer containing a description of what I've tried, and a viable workaround first suggested by @chui in a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update 2015-05-14

I contacted WRI support and they confirmed that this is a known issue with `Export` (support case: 3206586).

### Summary

@ChenStatsYu seems to have found an unexplained behavior of the `Export` function for PDF files that **looks like a bug**.

### Detailed results

**1)** I generated two graphics similar to those in the OP's original question, then exported them to PDF using `Export`. I am including the `Background -> None` option to `Plot` for completeness, but this is already the default for `Plot`, as one can check by running `Options[Plot]`. I have also separately tried without that explicit option. It does not make a difference to the discussion below.

```
Plot[
 {Exp[-(x - 7)^2/4], Exp[-(x - 5)^2/3]},
 {x, 0, 15},
 AxesLabel -> None,
 Ticks -> {Automatic, None},
 Axes -> {True, False},
 Background -> None
]
Export["nolegend.PDF", %]

Plot[
 {Exp[-(x - 7)^2/4], Exp[-(x - 5)^2/3]},
 {x, 0, 15},
 AxesLabel -> None,
 Ticks -> {Automatic, None},
 Axes -> {True, False},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 Background -> None
]
Export["withlegends.PDF", %]
```

**2)** I opened those two PDF files in a vector graphics program, and verified that the one generated from the graph without legends **included a white opaque panel placed behind the graphs**, effectively as a white background. This is the same construct that one would find when exporting the output of Plot containing a colored background.

**3)** Even though it was generated from completely equivalent expressions, the PDF generated from the legended graph **DID NOT CONTAIN that white panel**, effectively making the image transparent, as both should have been.

**4)** I reimported the PDF files back into *Mathematica*. Here are two two images attempting to summarize the relevant parts of those two files:

```
Grid[
  ArrayReshape[#, {2, 4}]& @( Graphics /@ Import["nolegend.PDF"][[1, 1]] ),
  Frame -> All
]
Grid[
  ArrayReshape[#, {2, 4}]& @( Graphics /@ Import["withlegends.PDF"][[1, 1]] ), 
  Frame -> All
]
```

**WITHOUT LEGENDS**
[image: structure of PDF without legends]

**WITH LEGENDS**
[image: structure of PDF with legends]

The second and third frames from the left in the top row of the structure of the imported PDF without legends are **two white opaque panels** of the same size as the curves. These panels are not there in the PDF with legends.

### chui's suggestion

**@chui** suggested in a comment to **include** `Background -> None` **as an option to** `Export`, rather than to `Plot`. He is onto something! Indeed, that fixed the exported PDF generated from the plot without legends. **The two extra white panels where not generated this time!** I generated the following "table of contents" from this latter PDF:

[image: exported PDF no legends, option in Export]

Comment: Specifying `Background->None` as an option to `Export` worked on my system too!

Answer (score 0):

```
Plot[{PDF[NormalDistribution[], x], PDF[NormalDistribution[-4, 1], x],
   PDF[NormalDistribution[2, 1], x]}, {x, -8, 6}, 
 AxesLabel -> {None, None}, Ticks -> {Automatic, None}, 
 Axes -> {True, False},
 Background -> None,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"N(0,1)", "N(-4,1)", "N(2,1)"}, {1, .5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I want to make the background disappear. Simply specifying a color would be not a very good general solution if that makes sense.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Your explicit question was "How do I make the first PDF like the second one?"  This problem is solved.  Your subsequent question about doing this without specifying the background seems impossible, since the background default is white (unless you use `SetOptions[Plot, Background -> LightBlue]`.  Your request to "make the background disappear" does not make sense.

Comment: The second PDF does not actually have a background. It's transparent. Sorry if there is any misunderstanding.

Comment: Again, I can't find the technical term for this. But the second PDF does not have a background color if you like. It only has the curves and axises and texts. It will show ANY color if I put it onto a different background.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu I think you are expressing your request correctly: you want these PDF files to be exported without a background, or equivalently with a transparent background.

Comment: `Background->None`?

Comment: @MarcoB There was a mis-spelling before anyone can see it! :)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yes, I think `Background -> None` should work, but @ChenStatsYu reported in our comment conversation above that it may not have worked for him.

Comment: Yes, I did not work on my system. Really odd! Windows 7 SP1 X64 with MMA V10.1.0, both English version.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu I just proved `Background->None` worked for me in version 10.1.  So if it works for you, I'd appreciate a check "acceptance" of my solution.

Comment: I will leave it on for the moment, so that others might suggest an alternate. But I will start a new post regarding my PDF situation. Because it is not working, for any reason.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The one with `PlotLegends ->` (second one) will work fine without the `Background->None`. Are you getting the same for the first graph as well? Thanks.

Comment: You might try specifying `Background->None` as an option to `Export`

Comment: @chuy That was an intriguing suggestion, and in fact it did fix the behavior! I looked in the documentation, however, and couldn't really find a reference for the usage you proposed. Had you come across this behavior before? I can't explain this behavior of `Export`, and it looks like a bug to me. If you have time, could you take a look at the description of my findings that I posted as an answer to this question?